# How to generate html documents from docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a Python project, and wrote many docstring in functions,

how to convert those docstring into html documentation in one or two steps,

I just want the Sphinx can act as doxygen, just convert all my comments or doctring into html documentation.

I run the `sphinx-quickstart` under the `docs` folder

then

```
> autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
```

then modified the conf.py `long_term_streaming_monitor/docs/source/conf.py`

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../src'))
```

Because all of my source code are put under `long_term_streaming_monitor/src`

The generated code is here [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ot3dw3oulxd1w3q/build.zip)

I followed the tutorial, but when I opened the index.html I got nothing, no module and methods listed on the html file
[link](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html)

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── _build
│   │   ├── doctrees
│   │   └── html
│   │       ├── _sources
│   │       └── _static
│   ├── _static
│   ├── _templates
│   └── html
└── src
    ├── long_term_streaming_monitor
    │   ├── log
    │   ├── scripts
    │   └── tests
    │       └── log
    └── long_term_streaming_monitor_.egg-info
```

Comment: Could you show us what happens when you run: ``make clean html``?

Comment: have your seen [`sphinx.ext.autodoc` docs](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in one of the comments you can use `sphinx.ext.autodoc`

More steps on quickstart [here](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html).
Check a example configuration file [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/src/conf.py)
Bonus - you can also integrate Travis with `sphinx` using [travis-sphinx](https://github.com/Syntaf/travis-sphinx) to autogenerate your github pages each time you push a code with new docstrings.